# How can i save changes i did to a prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I took the prefab and dragged him to the Hierarchy and then added as child more 4 capsules. Marked them in blue circles. But now how can i save it all as one updated prefab ?

[image: Prefab]

Comment: Drag it back to the project folder, first change the name

Comment: You haven't parented them underneath your prefab, it seems - how do you expect them to be grouped as a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply click on this button will save your prefab:

[image]

Comment: also `save project` to ensure all changes applied immediately.